# why does my css nor html load in codeigniter?

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

When I include the following code within my view file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();>css/libs/animate.min.css" type="text/css" media="all">

<!-- Font Awesome icon library -->
<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/libs/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">

<!-- Load primary stylesheet -->
<link rel="<?php echo base_url();?>stylesheet" href="css/skin.css" type="text/css" media="all">
```

Nothing loads not even HTML content,
but when I remove these lines HTML content loads properly.
So how do I load my CSS files? They are in my `assests/css`

Comment: Check permission of your css folder

Comment: which server are you using ?

Comment: you are doing it wrong no body should use xamp or wamp... better to use linux server with vagrant or virtual machine

Answer (score 1):

You have to load helper in config/autoload.php

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'file','form');
```

Comment: yeah this shows html content but still css not shown

Comment: Ok. Check your base url in config/config.php                    $config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com'

Comment: $config['base_url'] = ' ';

Comment: have you put css folder on root?

Answer (score 0):

in `config.php`]

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

and `base_url()` should

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

you did mistaken to close the php script in first css linking
you wrote .

```
 <?php echo base_url();>
```

instead of

```
<?php echo base_url();?>
```

and also check that you have loaded url helper in your code or not ?
use this

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/libs/animate.min.css" type="text/css" media="all">//mistake in this line missing '?'

    <!-- Font Awesome icon library -->
    <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/libs/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">

    <!-- Load primary stylesheet -->
    <link rel="<?php echo base_url();?>stylesheet" href="css/skin.css" type="text/css" media="all">
```

Comment: yeah i rectified this,also rectified this:<link rel="<?php echo base_url();
url helper there,but still css not loading

Comment: if you have rectified your code and also have loaded the url helper then error is not in that code check is your file exist in {{rootdirectory}}/css/libs/animate.min.css, and check what is your base_url value in your config file